# How to add conditional schema for cerberus

Tags: python-3.x, jsonschema, cerberus

```
{
  "offers": {
    "type": "list",
    "schema": {
      "type": "dict",
      "oneof":[{
      "schema": {
        "random1": {
          "type": "float",
          "empty": False
        },
        "random2": {
          "type": "float",
          "empty": False     
        }}}],
        "schema":{
        "offerId": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": True,
          "empty": False
        },
        "frequency": {
          "type": "string",
          "empty": False
        },
        "action": {
          "type": "string",
          "required": True,
          "empty": False
        }
      }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to validate the oneof schema and it is giving True when both random1 and random2 are not in the request. even i have tried with all other of-rules.can you help me with this?
like if i pass both fields in schema it should pass, if i have only one among the two it should pass, if i haven't pass both it should fail.